# How do I evaluate the following double integral over a general region

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I evaluate the following integral
$$ \int_{-1}^1 \int_{\arccos(y)}^{\pi} \sin(x)\sqrt {1+\sin^2 x} \,dx\,dy $$ 
I attempted to change the limits for the integrals

$$ \int_0^\pi \int_{\cos(x)}^1 \sin(x)\sqrt {1+\sin^2 x} \, dy\, dx$$

which I can integrate in respect to y giving
$$ \int_0^\pi (1)\sin(x)\sqrt {1+\sin^2 x} - \cos(x)\sin(x)\sqrt {1+\sin^2 x} \, dx$$

and I can integrate

$$ -\int_0^\pi \cos(x)\sin(x)\sqrt {1+\sin^2 x} \, dx =- \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)(\sin^2(x)+1)^{2/3}$$

but not $$ \int_0^\pi \sin(x)\sqrt {1+\sin^2 x} \, dx$$
My question is did I not flip the limits correctly in the beginning of my question to solve the integral or if my flipped limits are correct how do I integrate the final function because it seems more complicated than it should or is there another way of thinking about this integral that i'm not seeing. Thankyou for your time

Comment: You definitely changed limits correctly. Give me a sec to check the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything's correct so far. To evaluate the integral you were having problems with, rewrite the integrand as 
$$ \sin x \sqrt{2-\cos^2x}.$$
Then use the substitution $u=\cos x$. Finally, do a trig sub. Or, use Wolfram Alpha.